# There are coupled or decoupled bundles?

Tags: symfony, bundle, decoupling

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) of Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces said:

```
    With the **ResolveTargetEntityListener**, you are able to decouple your bundles, 
keeping them usable by themselves, 
    but still being able to define relationships between different objects
```

But what I see in the example that the `customer` entity located in `AppBundle` is already depended on the `InvoiceSubjectInterface` located in the `InvoiceBundle`. So AppBundle and InvoiceBundle aren't decoupled.

Can someone explain to me how these 2 bundles are decoupled as it is noted in the documentation?

Comment: The way I have occasionally implemented this capability was to have InvoiceInterface live inside of an Invoice component.  AppBundle,Invoice1Bundle,Invoice2Bundle would then all be dependent on this component.  Sort of decoupling them.  In practice, I found the resolve target capability to be more trouble than it is worth.